# How can I avoid daily reboots of my wireless router?

Tags: wireless-router, cable-modem

I recently decided to purchase my own cable modem (ISP decided to charge rent on the unit they provided), but have since had to reboot my wireless router daily.  I suspect the address provided by the ISP has a lease time of 24 hours, since the connection seems to drop out about the same time each day.

## The Symptoms:

At about the same time each day...

- All devices connected wirelessly lose internet connectivity.
- All devices connected to the router (wireless, or wired) can be pinged.
- Devices connected to the 5 port switch on the router maintain internet connectivity.

## The Cure:

Once the router has been rebooted, everything works as expected.

## The Setup:

### Devices:

- [NetGear N300 wireless router (WNR2000)](http://www.netgear.com/home/products/wirelessrouters/work-and-play/WNR2000.aspx)
- [Motorola SURFboard Cable Modem (SB6121)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B004XC6GJ0)

What can I do to prevent daily reboots?

Comment: I have the same cable modem, if your modem is rebooting, then its your ISP causing it to do so.  Your lease running out is NOT the reason your modem is rebooting.  This isn't a problem you can solve yourself, this is a service provider problem, the problem can only be fixed by your service provier.

Comment: @Ramhound It's not the modem that's rebooting.  I have to physically reboot my router, due to a lose of internet connectivity.

Comment: While I thought the modem was rebooting on its own, my suggestion still has merit, I had a similar problem about a year ago.  I did nothing and the problem eventually went away after 3 months.  The problem is your service provider, its either your line in the house, or the line comming in causing the problem.

Comment: Test this with another router... If the same problem persists, then contact your ISP!